# Scrape HTML table with Selenium and output as JSON using python

Tags: python, json, selenium, html-table

I am fairly new to python and I am trying to scrape a table from a website and output it as a JSON. I was able to use Selenium to get some data but I am not sure how to format is as a JSON. Also the table is paginated, how do I get the data on the other pages?

```
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Users/home/anaconda3/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://investor.vanguard.com/etf/profile/overview/VTI/portfolio-holdings")


for tr in driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("tr"):
    for td in tr.find_elements_by_tag_name("td"):
        print(td.get_attribute("innerText"))
```

Comment: "how do I get the data on the other pages" -- find either of the two links with the word "Next" then click on it. "not sure how to formate is as a json" -- well, you haven't shown us what you want your JSON to look like. Start with the [docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @JustinEzequiel. I will look for "next"....as for the json I am looking for it get be a table like the website. The purpose is to use this table for analytics.

Comment: "looking for it get be a table like the website" - JSON has no tables. You can have a list of lists, a list of dictionaries, a nested dictionary, etc. If you want somebody to answer, you need to at least show what the JSON you want looks like.